# SQL join from the same table

Tags: sql, select

How do I get  grand total for orders  made by credit card only from such a table :

```
order_id | meta_name | meta_value
___________________________________
1        | type      | credit
1        | total     | 1030.00
...
2        | type      | check
2        | total     | 930.00
..

3        | type      | credit
3        | total     | 330.00
```

what is the best way to describe such select operation if you are to search the Internet for a solution to this problem. 
suppose I am MySQL.

Comment: Which database system is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with either `join` or `group by`.  Here is the `join` method:

```
select ttype.order_id, cast(ttotal.meta_value as money)
from table ttype join
     table ttotal
     on ttype.order_id = ttotal.order_id and
        ttype.meta_name = 'type' and
        ttype.meta_value = 'credit' and
        ttotal.meta_name = 'total';
```

If yo could have more than one `total` for an `order`, then you would still want to aggregate:

```
select ttype.order_id, sum(cast(ttotal.meta_value as money))
from table ttype join
     table ttotal
     on ttype.order_id = ttotal.order_id and
        ttype.meta_name = 'type' and
        ttype.meta_value = 'credit' and
        ttotal.meta_name = 'total'
group by ttype.order_id
```

Comment: `meta_value`'s data type is something like varchar so you would have to convert it first.

Comment: @Szymon . . . That is true.  Many databases will convert strings that look like numbers to numbers in a numeric context.  That is a rather lame excuse, because I do think such conversions should be explicit.